# How to Convert plain text URLs into HTML hyperlinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, helper

There is a secure way to create a link when user write a string starting with www or ending with .com ?

For example if a user creating a post and write in the content "Visit google.com", the view create link automatically.

Code has to be sanitize to prevent damage?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

Comment: Thank you. Some people told me that rails_autolink gem is unsecure. Is true? Can I use it without damage?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [auto link gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink)
By default auto_link returns sanitized html_safe strings. This behaviour can be overridden by setting the :sanitize option to false (thus making it insecure if you don't have the content under control).